# Use a custom named php file in a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme for someone, based on an older modified theme, and it was using some AJAX scripting with Flash based "holders" for ad areas. I'm trying to use custom name phps to add image widgets to them.

So basically, I am trying to use a `<?php get_ad('variantnamehere'); ?>` and to get ad-customname.php from my theme files.

I assume I have to register those files within functions.php, but I have no idea how to do that.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Artur's feedback, I was able to find what I was looking for, thanks to the article [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress--wp-26419).

1. In functions.php, include your files using

`include ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/customfilename.php' );`

2. In your theme file where you wish to insert the code within that php file, add:

`<?php get_template_part('customfilename');?>`

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's functions.php add the following:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/ad-customname.php' );
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! I did try a few variants of that now, and the best I've come to was loading this line from my index.php `<div class="top-slideshow-advert"><?php get_ad728120(); ?></div>` as a standalone page. So the output was `<body>just the content of ad728120.php loaded here</body>`. Nothing else in the theme did load.